# Circumventing template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Suppose I am a user of a Certain Template Library (`CTL`) which defines a template, named, say, `Hector`

```
template <class T>
class Hector {...};
```

And in its documentation it gives many guarantees about `Hector` template behavior. 
But then it also defines a specialization for a certain type `Cool`

```
template <>
class Hector<Cool> {....};
```

The purpose of the specialization is a more optimized implementation of `Hector`, but unfortunately  because of this optimization many guarantees of `Hector` are violated.

Currently I really don't need the optimization, I'd rather preserve all the guarantees of `Hector`. Is there any way I could, without changing the library code (`CTL` is a highly respectable library, you know), circumvent the specialization? Any way at all? Maybe write some sort of wrapper? Anything? I just want to the compiler to generate code for `Hector<Cool>` in a normal, non-optimized way, with all the guarantees.

Comment: How about a wrapper class `struct Stool : public Cool { };`, and then use `Hector<Stool>`?

Comment: @Kerrek: Very funny, unfortunatly Cool is a typedef. I don't know it's a class or not :P

Comment: There is no such thing as the CTL. There is the Certain library, which originates from some CTL written years ago.

Comment: @Armen: Hah, but you said "class"! ;-) How about a wrapper `template <typename T> struct Drool;` which exposes `T` as a cast?

Comment: @Kerrel: OOps, that was a typo. Editing :)

Comment: +1 for sheer hilarity.

Comment: Actually, `class Hector` has an additional template parameter, the `Allevator`. ;)

Comment: YES! It happened! I was waiting to be downvoted! The question still remains - whY?!, but after free downvotes it's just a silly question. Anyway, everything is back to normal in SO. Next, they'll close the question as not constructive :))))

Comment: @Xeo: ITYM `Alligator`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you able to use the related template `Reque` that doesn't have the undesired specialization? Otherwise I think you'd need to create a wrapper for `Cool` so that the specialization isn't used.

Comment: I wanted to post this, forgot about it and now remembered it. :(

Answer (score 12):

You could wrap cool in a dummy type to prevent the template from specializing it.

Answer (score 8):

No. And even if it can be done in some esoteric fashion, don't. Circumventing language features should set off an alarm.

You have to wrap the value or use a different type like `char` instead of `bool` (they behave similarly), giving `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: who mentionned STDs and vectors ?

Comment: AFAIK the documentation gives no guaranteed that Cool and Shar have the same size, does it?

Comment: @Armen : It's possible that `Cool` is larger than `Shar` but not smaller, and `Shar` is guaranteed to be able to hold all well-defined values of `Cool`.

Comment: @Armen: Correct, `Cool` can have any size, not necessarily one, but `Shar` definitely has a size of one. That said, you can do some magic (perhaps implementation-specific) to pick a non-`Cool` integral type that has the same size as `Cool`.

Comment: The more I think about this question, the more I think this is the right answer. After all, if what you want is for `vector<bool>` to behave "correctly", then you must be willing to take addresses of elements (after all, you did not tell what you expect precisely from Ctd::Hector<Cool>). Therefore, using another integral type really makes sense (and will have the same semantics as bool, contrarily to the solution other people suggest with a wrapper). The good news is that you can even choose the size of the implementation.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a little generic disguiser:

```
template <typename T>
struct Drool
{
  Drool(T d) : b(d) { }
  inline operator T() const { return b; }
  inline Drool<T> & operator=(T d) { b = d; return *this; }
private:
  T b;
};
```

Now you can say `Hector<Drool<Cool>>`.

---

Improved version according to Xeo:

```
template <typename T>
struct Drool
{
  Drool(const T & d) : b(d) { }
  Drool(Drool && o) = default;

  inline operator const T & () const { return b; }
  inline operator       T & ()       { return b; }

private:
  T b;
};
```

Comment: Could be made even more generic by taking parameters as const-refs and adding a move-ctor for C++0x, but other than that, yeah. Also, no need for an `operator=`, as that is implicitly defined.

Comment: @Kerrek: Also, should be `operator T&()` and `operator T const&() const`. :)

Comment: @Xeo: I was actually wondering about that -- can the result of a cast be an lvalue?

Comment: @Xeo: Hm, OK, if I have `Drool<T> x; T y;` and I say `x = y;`, this already invokes `x = Drool<T>(y);`, so at what point would a cast come in useful as an lvalue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the <s>standard</s> certain implementation
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
4. Create a new file called `"my_hector.h"`
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
6. Remove the specialisation
7. Search and replace `#include <hector>` with `#include "my_hector.h"`
   [ Edit for @Xeo ;-) ]
8. Rename identifiers that begin with two leading underscores followed by a lowercase letter, and all identifiers that begin with a single leading underscore following by an uppercase letter.

Comment: I like this solution, actually :) Why not?

Comment: @Armen: Because user-code is not allowed to use `_Identifier` or `__identifier`? ;)

Comment: I don't like this solution because it gives up portability.

Comment: @Peter: It's not the standard implementation, it's a certain implementation :)

Comment: @Armen: I never said standard... /nonchalant

Comment: Fail for not reading. You changed the library code. I mean, didn't change the originating "file" that was downloaded, but creating your own library is paramount to changing the originating code.

Comment: @Xaade: Umm, how is writing your own code equivalent to changing other code?

Comment: If this certain implementation uses search paths, you can place your "hector" file in a directory that is searched before <hector>. That would save you step 7.

Comment: There is also an opportunity to break the ODR if you fail to replace `hector` by `my_hector.h` in *all* the indirectly included header files. So don't do this. Never. At least not on projects I'm working on. I wish I could downvote this more than once.

Comment: Instructions are incomplete - there's go guarantee that the template is implemented in a single file, and you might find yourself chasing down quite a lot of implementation-specific dependencies in order to isolate the certain implementation of Hector.

Comment: Another downvote for copypaste&tweak software development methodology.