# C++ std::basic_string/char_traits specialization

Tags: c++, string, templates, stdstring, char-traits

This is related to:

[std::basic_string specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547461/stdbasic-string-specialization) and 
[Circumventing template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499007/circumventing-template-specialization)

I tried the solution from [std::basic_string specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547461/stdbasic-string-specialization), but the problem is that CustomChar is a typedef for wchar_t and I have redefinition(conflict with specialization from std). How may I avoid usage of chart_traits when I'm not allowed to change CustomChar typedef?

Comment: You can supply an alternative `traits` class (i.e. something other than a `std::char_traits` specialization) while still using `wchar_t` as the `charT` template parameter to `std::basic_string`.

Comment: This is why C++ should be taken outside and shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer provided by Charles Bailey as a comment:

You can supply an alternative traits class (i.e. something other than a std::char_traits specialization) while still using wchar_t as the charT template parameter to std::basic_string

Answer (score 0):

You could use Boost's/C++0x's [`disable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/enable_if.html) to disable if there are known previous instantiations, like in the case of `char` and `wchar_t`.