# C++ swapping std::basic_string with differing char_traits

Tags: c++, string, move, swap

Searched around for this, but the best result has only been to copy the string.

Given this simple snippet:

```
struct custom_string_traits: std::char_traits<char> {
    static bool eq(char c, char d) { ... }
    static bool lt(char c, char d) { ... }
    ...
};
typedef std::basic_string<char,custom_string_traits> my_string;
```

how might I perform operations such as

```
std::string foo = "baz";
my_string bar = "qux";
x::swap(foo, bar);
/*  OR  */
foo = std::move(bar);
```

I want to optimize away from my current procedure:

```
std::string foo = "baz";
my_string bar = "qux";
my_string next(foo.c_str(), foo.size());
foo.assign(bar.c_str(), bar.size());
```

Looked at [C++ std::basic_string/char_traits specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548319/c-stdbasic-string-char-traits-specialization); not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Copying is does indeed appear to be the only way. Personally, I would use the iterator constructor, but I suppose that's just a matter of taste. You can avoid copying by using the same char_traits throughout.

Comment: @eerorika I have a case sensitive string (std::string) I need to convert to a case insensitive string (my_string). Otherwise I would use the same char_traits.

Comment: And you need to copy to do that.  You've shown the optimal solution.